# Fitting a histogram with Python - Complexe curves, intersection

Tags: python, histogram, curve

I have a [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IikAO.png)

And I want to perform a "comlex" curves algorithm. As you can see I have several modes. Near to 5-10 , near to 110-115 and near to 180. So I want a global gaussian curves and then 3 gaussian curves to fit with my modes.
Finally, I'm asking too much but I want the intersection between the 3 curves. I'm working on fault in geology and I just want to get my 3 families of fault directions.

Sorry it's really hard, could you help me please?

I tried this but it's not really working. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wh7b.png) is the output

```py
x_array = np.linspace(0, 180, 36)

amp1 = 700
sigma1 = 40
cen1 = 7

amp2 = 200
sigma2 = 10
cen2 = 65

amp3 = 750
sigma3 = 7
cen3 = 115


amp4 = 700
sigma4 = 4
cen4 = 172

y_array_4gauss = amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen1)/sigma1)**2))) + \
                amp2*(1/(sigma2*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen2)/sigma2)**2))) + \
                amp3*(1/(sigma3*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen3)/sigma3)**2))) + \
                amp4*(1/(sigma4*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen4)/sigma4)**2)))

def _4gaussianB(x, amp1,cen1,sigma1, amp2,cen2,sigma2,amp3,cen3,wid3,amp4,cen4,wid4,base):
    return base + amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen1)/sigma1)**2))) + \
            amp2*(1/(sigma2*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen2)/sigma2)**2)))+ \
            amp3*(1/(sigma3*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen3)/sigma3)**2)))+ \
            amp4*(1/(sigma4*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen4)/sigma4)**2)))
                
popt_4gauss, pcov_4gauss = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(_4gaussianB, x_array, y_array_4gauss, p0=[amp1,cen1,wid1,amp2,cen2,wid2,amp3,cen3,wid3,amp4,cen4,wid4, y_array_4gauss.min()], bounds=([0,x_array.min(),0,0,x_array.min(),0,0,x_array.min(),0,0,x_array.min(),0,0.9999*y_array_4gauss.min()],[np.inf,x_array.max(),np.inf,np.inf,x_array.max(),np.inf,np.inf,x_array.max(),np.inf,np.inf,x_array.max(),np.inf,y_array_4gauss.min()]))

# calcul des erreurs standards
perr_4gauss = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov_4gauss))
sd_1 = perr_4gauss[0:3]
sd_2 = perr_4gauss[3:6]
sd_3 = perr_4gauss[6:9]
sd_4 = perr_4gauss[9:12]

pars_1 = popt_4gauss[0:3]
pars_2 = popt_4gauss[3:6]
pars_3 = popt_4gauss[6:9]
pars_4 = popt_4gauss[9:12]


def _1gaussian(x, amp1,cen1,sigma1):
    return amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x_array-cen1)/sigma1)**2)))

gauss_peak_1 = _1gaussian(x_array, *pars_1)
gauss_peak_2 = _1gaussian(x_array, *pars_2)
gauss_peak_3 = _1gaussian(x_array, *pars_3)
gauss_peak_4 = _1gaussian(x_array, *pars_4)

# calcul des différences entre série et fonction
residual_4gauss = (y_array_4gauss) - (_4gaussianB(x_array, *popt_4gauss))

# prints the fitting parameters with their errors
if popt_4gauss.size>12:
    baselinevalue=popt_4gauss[12]
    print("-------------Baseline-------------")
    print("baseline value = %0.3f" % (baselinevalue))
print("-------------Peak 1-------------")
print("amplitude = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_1[0], sd_1[0]))
print("center = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_1[1], sd_1[1]))
print("sigma = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_1[2], sd_1[2]))
print("area = %0.2f" % np.trapz(gauss_peak_1))
print("-------------Peak 2-------------")
print("amplitude = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_2[0], sd_2[0]))
print("center = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_2[1], sd_2[1]))
print("sigma = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_2[2], sd_2[2]))
print("area = %0.2f" % np.trapz(gauss_peak_2))
print("-------------Peak 3-------------")
print("amplitude = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_3[0], sd_3[0]))
print("center = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_3[1], sd_3[1]))
print("sigma = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_3[2], sd_3[2]))
print("area = %0.2f" % np.trapz(gauss_peak_3))
print("-------------Peak 4-------------")
print("amplitude = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_4[0], sd_4[0]))
print("center = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_4[1], sd_4[1]))
print("sigma = %0.2f (+/-) %0.2f" % (pars_4[2], sd_4[2]))
print("area = %0.2f" % np.trapz(gauss_peak_4))
print("--------------------------------")

# Création de l'histogramme
hist, bins = np.histogram(valeurs, bins=36, range=(0, 180))



# Définir les graduations sur l'axe des abscisses (x) tous les 5 degrés
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 181, 5))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,1, height_ratios=[1,0.25])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
gs.update(hspace=0) 



# Affichage de l'histogramme avec des lignes de séparation entre les bins
ax1.bar(bins[:-1], hist, width=(bins[1]-bins[0]), color='blue', alpha=0.5, edgecolor='black')
ax1.grid(axis='x', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')

# peak 1
ax1.plot(x_array, gauss_peak_1+baselinevalue, "g")
ax1.fill_between(x_array, baseline, gauss_peak_1+baselinevalue, facecolor="green", alpha=0.5)
  
# peak 2
ax1.plot(x_array, gauss_peak_2+baselinevalue, "y")
ax1.fill_between(x_array, baseline, gauss_peak_2+baselinevalue, facecolor="yellow", alpha=0.5)  

# peak 3
ax1.plot(x_array, gauss_peak_3+baselinevalue, "y")
ax1.fill_between(x_array, baseline, gauss_peak_3+baselinevalue, facecolor="yellow", alpha=0.5)  

# peak 4
ax1.plot(x_array, gauss_peak_4+baselinevalue, "r")
ax1.fill_between(x_array, baseline, gauss_peak_4+baselinevalue, facecolor="red", alpha=0.5)  

# baseline
if baselinevalue!=0:
    baseline=np.ones(np.shape(x_array))*baselinevalue
    ax1.plot(x_array, baseline, "k-.",label='baseline')
    ax1.fill_between(x_array, 0, baseline, facecolor="grey", alpha=0.5)

# distribution
ax1.plot(x_array, y_array_4gauss, "ro")
ax1.plot(x_array, _4gaussianB(x_array, *popt_4gauss), 'k--',label='best fitting curve')

# residual
ax2.plot(x_array, residual_4gauss, "bo", label="Abs. Residual average = %0.3f" % (abs(residual_4gauss)).mean())
    


ax2.set_xlim(-5,105)
ax2.set_ylim(residual_4gauss.min()-(0.6*np.ptp(residual_4gauss)),residual_4gauss.max()+(0.2*np.ptp(residual_4gauss)))

ax2.set_xlabel("x_array",family="serif",  fontsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel("y_array",family="serif",  fontsize=12)
ax2.set_ylabel("Res.",family="serif",  fontsize=12)

ax1.legend(loc="best")
ax2.legend(loc="best")

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(20))
#ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(50))

ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())

ax1.tick_params(axis='x',which='major', direction="out", top="on", right="on", bottom="off", length=8, labelsize=8)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor', direction="out", top="on", right="on", bottom="off", length=5, labelsize=8)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y',which='major', direction="out", top="on", right="on", bottom="off", length=8, labelsize=8)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y',which='minor', direction="out", top="on", right="on", bottom="on", length=5, labelsize=8)

ax2.tick_params(axis='x',which='major', direction="out", top="off", right="on", bottom="on", length=8, labelsize=8)
ax2.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor', direction="out", top="off", right="on", bottom="on", length=5, labelsize=8)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y',which='major', direction="out", top="off", right="on", bottom="on", length=8, labelsize=8)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y',which='minor', direction="out", top="off", right="on", bottom="on", length=5, labelsize=8)

fig.tight_layout()
#fig.savefig("fit2Gaussian_peaks_resid.png", format="png",dpi=1000)
```